# Sharepoint ResolvePrincipals reverse method

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Having the code above:

```
SPPeopleService.People peopleService = new SPPeopleService.People();
peopleService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, 
                            CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, CREDENTIAL_DOMAIN);
peopleService.Url = "http://{mySite}/people.asmx";

String[] users = new String[] {"user1"};
SPPeopleService.PrincipalInfo[] principleInfoUser = 
                    peopleService.ResolvePrincipals(users, 
                          SPPeopleService.SPPrincipalType.User, true);
```

String UserID = principleInfoUser[0].UserInfoID.ToString();
String UserFormat = principleInfoUser[0].UserInfoID.ToString() + ";#" + principleInfoUser[0].AccountName.ToString();

Using the **ResolvePrincipals()** method from **People** service, this is what I get:

-ResolvePrincipals("user1") => return: domain\user1

-ResolvePrincipals("User Firstname1") => return: domain\user1

**I want to obtain the opposite: 
giving "*domain\user1*", obtain "*User Fistname1*"**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why cannot you use the same method? You can provide user login names as parameter and then from the result (array of PrincipalInfo objects) get DisplayName property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcpeople.principalinfo_members(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That's it! With the **DisplayName** property now I have it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same method: provide user login name as parameter and then from the result (array of PrincipalInfo objects) get DisplayName property.

```
SPPeopleService.People peopleService = new SPPeopleService.People();
peopleService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, 
                                CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, CREDENTIAL_DOMAIN);
peopleService.Url = "http://{mySite}/people.asmx";

String[] users = new String[] {"domain\user1"};
SPPeopleService.PrincipalInfo[] principleInfoUser = 
                        peopleService.ResolvePrincipals(users, 
                              SPPeopleService.SPPrincipalType.User, true);
String displayName = principleInfoUser[0].DisplayName;
```